# Когда я перестану быть новым участником?

Tags: поддержка, новые-участники

Прям необходимости нет, но просто интересно.

Comment: Если вы об индикаторе нового пользователя, который показывается другим участникам при попытке ответить на ваш вопрос - то через неделю после вашего первого поста на сайте.

Comment: @PashaPash, ну в ответы же.

Comment: Вот я тоже думаю - самому отвечать или пусть так останется. Вот дилемма...

Comment: отвечай конечно :-)

Comment: @Qwertiy с телефона тяжело в ответы :(

Comment: @Miron программируете тоже с телефона?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Индикатор нового пользователя снимется автоматически через неделю после первого поста на сайте.

Анонс об этом индикаторе на MSE: [Come Take a Look at our New Contributor Indicator!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314287/)